# AWS LexRuntime API - send an audio

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, audio, aws-sdk, web-audio-api

I'm trying to implement a bot using `AWS Lex`, in my case (POC only) the browser request the AWS API directly without a proxy, in the POC i need to make a text and audio bot conversations, that supported by `Lex`.

I'm using the `aws-sdk` package and I'm following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntime.html#postContent-property) official documentation.

For text, the API works well and I succeed to implement a bot conversation, but when I'm trying to send an audio it's not working or gives me errors about wrong formats.

This is the POST parameter of the `inputStream` format:

[image]

It's also required to send a `contentType` based on the data provided (audio in my case):

[image]

Do anyone know how can I get this such data from the user microphone using JavaScript?

I already played around with `navigator.getUserMedia`, `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`, `AudioContext`, `recorder.onaudioprocess`, `MediaRecorder` and more, to get any type of data mentioned in the `inputStream` parameter above, but nothing is actually worked.

Thanks to the helpers!

Comment: wow that's too bad nobody has answered here. How did you do it?

Comment: Don't exactly remember what it was, but I did remember I played with it a lot until it finally worked. here is the code I extracted from my project: https://gist.github.com/shlomisas/aab007c05c4aca648103312f060a8e5b, it's a Recorder wrapper class i prepared to make things more easy to use. at the end of the file you can see how i'm using it together with Lex SDK. hope it'll works..

p.s. It's working as part of the project so maybe you need to modify it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't exactly remember what it was, but I played with it a lot until it finally worked.

Here is the code I extracted from my project: gist.github.com/shlomisas/aab007c05c4aca648103312f060a8e5b.

It's a Recorder wrapper class I prepared to make things easier to use. 
At the end of the file you can see how i'm using it together with Lex SDK. hope it'll works.

p.s. It's working as part of the project so maybe you need to modify it a bit.